# Can we limit Swift generated interface accessible from module only in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, module, buck

**Case**

A module (static library with module-map file) is having mixed code (Objective-C + Swift) in an iOS App codebase.
The Swift code need to be used from module only, so all interface required is *internal*

The documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c) says

> Because the generated header is part of the framework’s public
>   interface, only declarations marked with the public or open modifier
>   appear in the generated header for a framework target. Methods and
>   properties that are marked with the internal modifier and declared
>   within a class that inherits from an Objective-C class are accessible
>   to the Objective-C runtime. However, they're inaccessible at compile
>   time and don't appear in the generated header for a framework target.

On XCode I am able to compile project successfully but on our CI machine which is using [BUCK](https://buckbuild.com/) to build is failing as it cannot find Swift methods defined internal from Objective C code *within* the module. The fix that worked is making those methods public.

My doubts:

- Is this a bug in XCode, as documentation implies that Swift methods that we want to use from Objective C has to be public?
- Do we need to mark all interface required within module as *public*,
  even though we are using it from within the module?

> Generated header is part of the framework’s public interface

- Even if the generated header is not declared in modulemap (or
  umbrella    header), will it remain framework's public interface?
  What if the Swift is being used from within module only and I don't
  want to expose it to other modules?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: It is difficult to explain. For me it worked fine on XCode but not on CI machines using BUCK to build. But now I am confused because of this documentation. I can't make them internal as BUCK build is failing and I don't know much about BUCK to investigate

Comment: Also I updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible as of now. I was wrong saying that it worked with XCode. There is an [enhancement](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5221) request logged for it in the Swift repo.